# Is there a way to change screen brightness on macOS using "/sys-like" folder?

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

From what I understand, Mac OS doesn't have a `/sys` folder to access the kernel interface. If I wanted to change the brightness of the screen, how would I do this using only terminal commands?

I'm generally also curious as to whether there is a `sys`-like folder with a kernel interface on MacOS in general that I can tinker with. Thanks!

Comment: There is no `/sys` interface AFAIK on macOS. Regarding screen brightness, see https://osxdaily.com/2019/08/14/change-screen-brightness-mac-terminal/

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm new to Mac OS scripting. Does this typically require using Applescript? I would ideally not want to install third-party libraries to perform these actions.

Comment: Applescript is built into macOS, supplied by Apple, present on all Macs.